# What is the best way to handle multiple "add" screens

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am making an android app, using Xamarin, that allows a user to add and then view various types of information. Currently I made an 'add item' screen for each type of information the user is able to store but that is currently 11 screens and when I add the display views then that is 11 more. Eventually that could grow to even more. Is there a better way to handle this sort of thing?

**More Detail:**

To do a very simple example using 2 items, lets say a user can store the following information about a Car:

1. Exterior Color
2. Interior Color
3. Amount of Doors.

Then lets say the user can store the following about a Building:

1. Amt of Floors
2. Address
3. Phone Number

For the car 'add item' screen I would want textviews and plainviews for each of that information and then lets say I would want a box at the bottom to allow a user to upload an image. Then for the building 'add item' screen i want to have, again, textviews and plainviews for each piece of information but this time I want there to be a box for notes at the bottom instead.

Again this is a simple example. In reality the screens look pretty different overall but serve the same functionality in the sense that they allow a user to add information, but that information is also much different then each other for the most part.

**TLDR**: What is the best way to handle screens that serve the same relative purpose but look differently? Do I make separate activities and layouts for each add screen or is there a way to use a master layout/activity that changes based on the type of item being added?

**PS:** I do not think using Xamarin plays any part in this but I wanted to mention it to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to handle screens that serve the same relative purpose but look differently?

1. Abstract out the same part of the layouts. For example Both your "car" and "Building" layout should have "upload image" mode. when you design this kind of layout. You can use `<include>` tag as follows

   ```
   <include
       layout="@layout/upload_image"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   ```
2. Dynamic layout is also suitable for you. For example both "car" and "Building" layout need some textView, your can write as following code:

   ```
   public class DynamicLayout : LinearLayout
   {
       private List<LinearLayout> layouts;

       public DynamicLayout(Context context, int textViewcount) : base(context)
       {
           this.Initialize(textViewcount);
       }

       protected override void OnSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
       {
           base.OnSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

           foreach (var l in layouts)
           {
               l.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w / layouts.Count, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
           }
       }

       private void Initialize(int textViewcount)
       {
           this.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
           layouts = new List<LinearLayout>();
           for (int n = 0; n < textViewcount; n++)
           {
               var layout = new LinearLayout(this.Context)
               {
                   Orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                   LayoutParameters =
                           new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(this.Width / textViewcount, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)
               };

               layouts.Add(layout);
               if ("car")
               {
                   var textView = new TextView(this.Context)
                   {
                       Text = "Car"
                   };
                   layout.AddView(textView);
               }
               else if ("building")
               {
                   var textView = new TextView(this.Context)
                   {
                       Text = "building"
                   };
                   layout.AddView(textView);
               }


               this.AddView(layout);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   But Dynamic layout is hard to control the display of the views. If the two methods are used in combination that could be better.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. This more or less gave me the information I needed to know.